# High-Level Design Patterns or Not Reinventing The Wheel

Tags: design-patterns, data-modeling

The Holy Grail of programming is to solve a problem once and make continual reuse of that solution forevermore.  And, yet, despite my best efforts I find that I am often reworking familiar problems.  So GoF design patterns aside, there have been several times that I've designed calendaring, content management, and person/organization address books to name only a few.

I'd like to know if there are any good resources (books, websites, whatever) where I could peruse common high-level business designs.  I do realize that the requirements between my project and any pattern I might discover will differ, but I do expect the heart of the matter would remain the same, that there would be a lot of hard-won experience from which to draw.  Plus, as geekish as this is, I simply enjoy reading about the process and the rationale behind the decisions from which designs emerge.  I love it when shops, startups, and coders are transparent about their designs.  (e.g. 37Signals, Garret Dimon)

This [post](http://gadgetopia.com/post/4098) touches on the subject and calls these high-level design patterns "Functional Design Patterns", but I'm not sure that's the common term used for what I'm describing.  A search on "Functional Design Patterns" didn't turn up much.  I also searched on "Domain-Specific Design Patterns" and "Data Model Design Patterns", the latter provided [an interesting result](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/advanceddm.htm) so maybe this is more on target.  By what term do you know what I'm trying to describe?  Any good resources?  Any other shops/coders who transparently showcase their emerging designs?

Comment: Could this perhaps be Domain-Driven Design Patterns?

Comment: Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture is supposed to be good; I haven't read that one yet though. http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420

Comment: Hey, SO posters like re-inventing the wheel. It's keeps them off the streets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think about Analysis Pattern.

> I believe it came reading Martin Fowler. (Google shows me my memory was right...)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't heard of [the Hillside Group](http://www.hillside.net/), the [Pattern Languages of Programs](http://www.hillside.net/conferences/plop.htm) events, or [the books that have come out of this effort](http://www.hillside.net/patterns/books/index.htm), I would start there. I have been nothing but happy about this effort.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at data modeling, in-particular the [conceptual schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_schema)?

I think you've got to be mindful of what  can realistically achieve with such abstract patterns. The more abstract a pattern is the less implementation detail it can provide. The devil is in the detail - therefore abstract patterns still leave work to be done.

I don't believe there is a single solution that could address all possible problems. From a pragmatic stand point I would argue that it's more useful to investigate methods for managing complexity rather than patterns which can address every single problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following - not sure as to how relevant they'll to you :)

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)
- http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/
- http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/

Book commonly referenced:
- *Design Patterns* by Gamma, Helm, Johnson and Vlissides (Addison Wesley Longman, 1995.  ISBN 0-201-63361-2)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all, for the feedback.  I was aware of the low-level design patterns common to a programmer's toolbox and I had visited Hillside Group in the past.  I will spend more time there.

As I investigate further, I think the design patterns I'm after are closely related to data modeling.  I am reworking a calendaring data model I threw together and due to emerging requirements some of the enhancements/fixes were a bit awkward.  Unfortunately, as design goes, sometimes I have to head far enough down a path, let the requirements emerge,  backtrack a bit, and then remodel based on shortcomings discovered from experience.  From my experience, the data model plays a huge role in determining not only the elegance of the system, but also its UI.

I'll stay posted for other resources that are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

For good data modeling books:

Hay: Enterprise Model Patterns

Fowler: Analysis Patterns

Silverston: Data Model Resource Book (Vols 1,2,3)

Blaha: Pattenrs of Data Modeling